# Toilet Tank Replacement

Tags: bathroom

My Lamosa Toilet tank SAHARA 411, 17"X8" needs to be replaced.  Can't find another Sahara 411 tank.
Can I replace this tank with a Lamosa 16"x8" SASA
Vortens Glacier Bay 412 Tank?
If not, what other toilet tank companies would fit on the Lamosa toilet?
I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: You might be better off contacting the manufacturer. It appears that this is their SanitaryWare contact site:  https://www.coronamexico.com/contacto

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, as @jwh20 said, we won't be able to help you: contact the manufacturer. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.